# Does Hill University (USA) have legitimate accreditation?

Tags: university, united-states, accreditation

I need to know if [Hill University](https://web.archive.org/web/20150518065254/http://www.hilluniversity.com/) is accredited. Especially in the field of MBA degrees.

Comment: Why do you say "Hill University (USA)"? I don't see anything on their site that suggests any particular connection to the United States.

Comment: It's a [diploma mill](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diploma_mill). Don't waste your time or your money.

Answer (score 22):

The [Hill University's](http://www.hilluniversity.com), website dead as of Sept 2015*, [accreditation page](http://www.hilluniversity.com/university/accreditation.asp) did not make it clear which of their degrees were accredited, instead the two accrediting bodies (IOEAB and OKOLA) are [listed at this random website](http://www.geteducated.com/college-degree-mills/204-fake-agencies-for-college-accreditation) as "fake degree accreditation agencies". They are also the accrediting agencies used by [Speedy Degrees](http://www.speedydegrees.com/speedydegrees/accreditation.asp) which would suggest to me that accreditation by those bodies is more or less meaningless.

Further, the web domain is .com and not .edu which is highly atypical for US universities. The [requirements for .edu domain](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/.edu) require a US location and "proper" accreditation. While not using a .edu domain could be related to the online nature of the university, it is also a warning sign that the accreditation might be questionable.

* Recent reports by [NYTimes](http://www.nytimes.com/2015/05/17/world/asia/tracking-axacts-websites.html?_r=0) and [UIUC](http://www.hep.uiuc.edu/home/g-gollin/pigeons/) list this university as a fake.

Comment: Their webpages also [use stock images](http://goo.gl/PXmHta), another strong indicator of an unaccredited degree mill.  Google Search-by-Image is one of the easier ways to detect imposter institutions.

Comment: In fact, the entire text of that page is clearly plagiarized from http://www.edinburgheducation.net/accreditation.html ... which may itself be an imposter.

Comment: It might be the other way round, since the EE webpage mentikns Hill as if they did a faulty search-and-replace http://www.edinburgheducation.net/about.html

Comment: Note: .edu *now* requires "proper" accreditation, but people who had .edu domains before the early 2000s were grandfathered in; .edu doesn't necessarily guarantee proper accreditation.

Comment: For what it's worth, it is possible for an online-only university which has a recognized US accreditation to get a .edu domain.  [Example](http://www.waldenu.edu/).  So the fact that Hill University doesn't have one is more likely related to lack of accreditation than its business model.

Comment: A list of accrediting organizations for US universities is [available from Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_recognized_higher_education_accreditation_organizations#United_States). Note that in general individual degree programs are not accredited; only the universities as a whole are.

Comment: @FerasAlSoufi I suggest doing your own web searches on both the individual behind the first web site you list, and the organizations behind the other three, before deciding.

Comment: Please modify the answer to account for what Nate has said.